# Why is my javascript parameter undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function call:

```
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var style = $.trim($(this).find(".tdStyle").html());
    var qtyOnHand = $.trim($(this).find(".tdQtyOnHand").html());
    var PlantID = $.trim($(this).find(".tdPlantID").html());
    var Size = $.trim($(this).find(".tdSize").html());

    dialogOpen(id, style, qtyOnHand, $(this), Size);
```

I am trying to pass multiple values into my dialogOpen function by grabbing values from various elements.  Every value is works fine in my dialogOpen function shown below with the exception of the last one _Size.  I test the value of _Size before I get to dialogOpen with the following:

```
var _Size = ($.trim($(this).find(".tdSize").html())); 
console.log(_Size);
```

console.log shows 2.378

Here is the beginning of my code for my function where I get the undefined (on xSize):

```
function dialogOpen(ID, style, QtyOnHand, row, PlantID, xSize) 
{
debugger;
console.log(xSize);
$('#dialogForm').dialog({
title: 'Enter Quantity',
height: 200,
```

Comment: I would set each trim statement to variable and then console log all of them to be sure you are getting what you expect, then pass variables into the dialogOpen() call once you know the values are correct. Too messy with the trims inside the call you'll never figure out where the issue is. Also, I wouldn't start variables with _, it might be causing issues.

Comment: I'll try that and report back.  I only set the variable with _ as a test to make sure there was not a scope issue.  Thanks.

Comment: in dialoadOpen method can you check `console.log(arguments)`

Comment: Also, what is tdSize? An input? A table cell? Not all elements use .html(), some are .text or .val().

Comment: If you talk about scope issue: hoisting. If you define and set the variable after you log it, you get `undefined`, in contrast to `unexpected identifier`. Hope that helps.

Comment: tdSize is a table cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are six parameters, and only five values in the call.

You have placed the parentheses wrong for the second to last value, so the two last values are inside a parenthesis with the comma operator between them.

You have:

```
$.trim($(this).find(".tdPlantID").html(), _Size)
```

but you should have:

```
$.trim($(this).find(".tdPlantID").html()), _Size
```

Comment: Wow.  I can't believe I did that.  Thanks Guffa.

Answer (score 2):

You're only sending 5 arguments. Probably just a mistake. Change this:

```
dialogOpen($(this).attr("id"), $.trim($(this).find(".tdStyle").html()), $.trim($(this).find(".tdQtyOnHand").html()), $(this), $.trim($(this).find(".tdPlantID").html(), _Size));
```

To this:

```
dialogOpen($(this).attr("id"), $.trim($(this).find(".tdStyle").html()), $.trim($(this).find(".tdQtyOnHand").html()), $(this), $.trim($(this).find(".tdPlantID").html()), _Size);
```